# Invalid HTTP_HOST header: The domain name provided is not valid -- requests to dockerized django app using container name

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

Within an app composed of multiple microservices run via docker-compose, I need a way to make a request from one container (`app` via flask & requests), directly to the other (`chart`/django):

This is a simplified version of what I'm attempting.

routes.py:

```
@APP.route('/post_data', methods=['POST'])
def post_data():
  post_data = request.get_json()
  response = requests.post('http://chart_app_1:8080/json/', data=post_data)
  return response.text
```

The response I get is an error message:

```
django.core.exceptions.DisallowedHost: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'chart_app_1:8080'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035
```

I'm able to make exactly this kind of request to other containers running flask apps, with no problems. I don't have any control over whether or not we use Django for this particular microservice though.

It seems that this might be because the hostname has an underscore in it: [see this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/zulip-devel/r1v8DNlsjSU/w6aBra5UAgAJ).  Is there a way around this? It seems like it must be possible to make a simple request between containers.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In the docker-compose file, modify the service name for avoiding underscores in the Django service.

That's the only way that I know for avoiding the error as it's not a Docker limitation.

Comment: It looks like setting `container_name` will prevent it from scaling - that's okay in development. For production, I'll set an environment variable to be the container's public url.

Comment: It's an RFC 1034/1035 thing. A hostname cannot contain underscores and your docker container's hostname on the network is `chart_app_1`. You need to rename your docker server to remove the underscores.

Comment: @TomSaleeba thank you. me and my colleague were stuck on it :|

Comment: That's not a Django problem, hostnames can't contain underscores.

Comment: Worked a charm!